# Visual C++ failure to include

Tags: windows, namespaces, include, c++-cli, clr

I have two mutually dependent header files: BarP.h and addNewProductForm.h, built using Microsoft CLR components, which look something like this (they are way too long to include intact):
BarP.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "addNewProductForm.h"
#include "editBarOptionsForm.h"
#include "editDecayParamsForm.h"
#include "editExistingItemForm.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <msclr\marshal.h>


namespace BarPricer3 {

    using namespace std;
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace msclr::interop;

ref struct productDat{...};
productDat^ createProduct(String^ name,double firstPrice,double lastPrice,double lastDemand){...};
public ref class BarP{
    ...
    private: System::Void createNewProductForm(...){
        BarPricer3::addNewProductForm^ newProductForm = gcnew addNewProductForm;
        newProductForm->ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

addNewProductForm.h

```
#pragma once

#include "BarP.h"
#include <fstream>

namespace BarPricer3 {

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public ref class addNewProductForm{
        ...
    private: System::Void createNewProduct(...){
         productDat^ theNewP = createProduct(this->name->Text,Convert::ToDouble(this->firstPrice->Text),Convert::ToDouble(this->lastPrice->Text),Convert::ToDouble(this->lastDemand->Text));
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following errors:
Error   8   error C2039: 'addNewProductForm' : is not a member of 'BarPricer3'  d:...\BarP.h   690 (line 32 in my code)
Error   15  error C2065: 'productDat' : undeclared identifier   d:...\addNewProductForm.h  181 (line 19 in my code)

Can I get any advice about what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular inclusion in the header files, and that, combined with the `#pragma once` directive, is what yields the error. You need to remove one of the includes (or both) and replace them with a **forward declaration** (might want to google this).

You'll probably need to separate the implementations to a different file, because you use the types inside the headers.

Your problem is that `addNewProductForm.h` uses `productDat` which is defined in `BarP.h`, and that `BarP.h` uses `addNewProductForm` which is defined in `addNewProductForm.h`. (These are the classes that will need to be forward-declared).

Comment: Thanks. Isn't the `#pragma once` directive meant to avoid the circular inclusion, or am I totally missing something there?

Comment: @deftfyodor no, the pragma directive is equivalent to include  guards. The same file isn't included more than once, but that's it. You still have to deal with circular dependencies.